# How to mount Hibernate Windows partition with read/write access?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, windows, hibernate

How can I mount Hibernate Windows partition? 
Here is the things! 
1) I don't want to shutdown the Windows completely. 
2) I want to mount with full read/write access. 
3) I don't want to delete hiberfil.sys file to mount. 
I searched around the web, and all the answers suggested to shutdown or delete hiberfil file. I just want to edit something without damaging my hibernate sessions. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You 'just' want to tinker with the engine...while the aircraft is in flight. You might be bored in your seat, but that engine, and the rest of the aircraft, have a rather different perspective. Consider 'just' doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't any safe way of mounting a hibernated partition of Windows on Ubuntu without deleting hiberfil.sys. This is because it contains running processes and can potentially crash your system if deleted. You can see this post [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/145902/688775) for more information about hibernation in Windows.

Comment: Yes, I know the operating system concept. Logically, Ubuntu suppose to be able to mount the hibernate Windows partition because hiberfil.sys file is nothing to Linux. We all know that it is dangerous for sessions we kept. I believe there will be a way to mount with r/w access without deleting hiberfil.sys file.

Comment: @AlexanderBeatson In the post linked point three explains mounting the drive with read and write enabled. Also, you will need to destroy the hiberfil.sys to gain access to the drive according to the post, removing all session data.

Answer (score 0):

Also Windows users, create a cmd desktop link, left click desktop, call new icon, type cmd, click, type in cmd.exe in dialogue box,
Now left click that and run as administrator, dialogue box opens. Type in powercfg /h off
Hit enter
Hibernate is now turned off